# How to edit Virtual Hard Drives(vhd) with C#?

Tags: c#, .net, virtualization, vhd

I have a given .vhd-File and want to edit it programmatically in C# WITHOUT MOUNTING IT.
Does anyone know how to do this(possibly with an api or library)?

Comment: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb676673.aspx  :P

Comment: Do you mean you just want to open it as a disk you can write to using C#?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at discutils. Might be what you want.

http://discutils.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 1):

you can use discutils: http://discutils.codeplex.com/

"DiscUtils is a .NET library to read and write ISO files and Virtual Machine disk files (VHD, VDI, XVA, VMDK, etc). DiscUtils is developed in C# with no native code (or P/Invoke)."